# How to notify my Alexa Skill's customer about new features?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an Alexa Skill, and before releasing the first version of it, I wanted to be sure that I can notify my users about new features.

How can I do this ? What are my options ?

I saw [Alexa Proactive Event](https://developer.amazon.com/fr/docs/smapi/proactive-events-api.html), but I'm not sure about how to use it and if it's the right choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following options:

### Visually

(of course who reads when using alexa ;-) )

- alexa developer console -> distribution -> whats new
- For my skills I also updated the "detailed description" with some mini release notes before this "whats new" text field existed.

### Voice

You can check in your backend logic if your user uses the skill after your update.

- Therefore you would need to save the time whenever a user uses your skill (of course you need the times before your update but a backend update is independent from your skill update with certification).
- Now if a requests come in you check the lastUsage time and can send out your special update message. 
  Of course you could also do via a flag (flag all users which got the message) instead of lastUsageTime.
- Will be helpfull for persisting this data (alreadyGotUpdate message flag or lastSkillUsageTime): https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/manage-attributes.html#persistenceadapter